# HTTP 404 with CXF (JAX-RS), Spring and Tomcat (no web.xml)

Tags: java, xml, maven, tomcat, cxf

Hi people of stackoverflow,

I got an HTTP 404 when I start the application in Eclipse by "Run on server". My external Tomcat is configured within Eclipse.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**KasInitializer.java**

```
public class KasInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String SERVICE_PATH = "/I_Attachment_Services";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AttachmentServicesConfig.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("CXFServlet",
            new CXFServlet());
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(SERVICE_PATH);
    }
}
```

**AttachmentServicesApplication.java**

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class AttachmentServicesApplication extends Application {

}
```

**AttachmentServicesConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:kas.properties")
public class AttachmentServicesConfig {

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public SpringBus cxf() {

        return new SpringBus();
    }

    @Bean
    public Server jaxRsServer() {

        JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance()
            .createEndpoint(attachmentsApplication(), JAXRSServerFactoryBean.class);
        factory.setServiceBeans(
            Arrays.<Object>asList(attachmentsController(attachmentService(attachmentRepo()))));
        factory.setAddress(factory.getAddress());
        factory.setProviders(Arrays.<Object>asList(jsonProvider()));
        return factory.create();
    }

    @Bean
    public AttachmentServicesApplication attachmentsApplication() {

        return new AttachmentServicesApplication();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider() {

        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }


    @Bean
    public AttachmentREST attachmentsController(AttachmentService attachmentService) {

        return new AttachmentRESTImpl(attachmentService);
    }

    @Bean
    public AttachmentService attachmentService(AttachmentFileStorage repo) {

        return new AttachmentServiceImpl(repo);
    }

    @Bean
    public AttachmentFileStorage attachmentRepo() {

        return new AttachmentFileStorageImpl();
    }
}
```

**AttachmentREST.java**

```
@Path("/")
public interface AttachmentREST {

    @GET
    @Path("/MaxMailSize")
    @Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
    Response readMaxMailSize();
    
    ...
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.cgm.de.connectivity.ti.kim</groupId>
    <artifactId>kas</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0-0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>kas-server</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <warName>I_Attachment_Services</warName>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.0</version> <configuration> <archive> <manifest> <mainclass>com.cgm.de.connectivity.ti.kim.kas.server.KASServer</mainclass> 
            </manifest> </archive> </configuration> </plugin> -->
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- === inherited dependencies === -->

    <!-- kas-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId> ${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>kas-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CXF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- === project-specific dependencies === -->

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies></project>
```

**console output:**

```
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server built:          Nov 3 2018 17:39:20 UTC
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Server number:         8.5.35.0
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Name:               Linux
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: OS Version:            5.9.12-050912-generic
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Java Home:             /home/pepe/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.265-zulu/jre
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Version:           1.8.0_265-b11
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: JVM Vendor:            Azul Systems, Inc.
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/pepe/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/pepe/tools/server/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.35
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/pepe/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/pepe/tools/server/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.35
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/pepe/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/pepe/tools/server/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.35/endorsed
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMATION: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMATION: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMATION: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMATION: Initialization processed in 525 ms
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service [Catalina]
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.35
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:50 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:51 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMATION: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:32:51.719 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
13:32:52.298 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl - Setting the server's publish address to be /
13:32:52.374 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext initialized in 651 ms
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 28, 2021 1:32:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMATION: Server startup in 2839 ms
```

**EDIT:**

When I copy the war file into ../tomcat/webapps folder manually and start tomcat like "./catalina.sh run" then I get the following line in localhost.2021-04-28.log:

```
28-Apr-2021 15:15:12.912 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
28-Apr-2021 15:15:13.315 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
28-Apr-2021 15:15:14.170 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
28-Apr-2021 15:15:14.170 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
28-Apr-2021 15:15:14.172 INFORMATION [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@491ac41a')
```

But in localhost_access_log.2021-04-28.txt:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [28/Apr/2021:15:15:48 +0200] "GET /I_Attachment_Services/MaxMailSize HTTP/1.1" 404 1111
```

**EDIT 2:**

When I deploy the same application on an embedded Tomcat everything works fine:

```
public class KasTomcatServer {

    private static final String SERVICE_PATH = "/I_Attachment_Services/*";
    private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/";
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final File base = createBaseDirectory();

        final Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(PORT);
        tomcat.setBaseDir(base.getAbsolutePath());

        Context context = tomcat.addContext(CONTEXT_PATH, base.getAbsolutePath());
        Tomcat.addServlet(context, "CXFServlet", new CXFServlet());

        context.addServletMapping(SERVICE_PATH, "CXFServlet");
        context.addApplicationListener(ContextLoaderListener.class.getName());
        context.setLoader(new WebappLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()));

        context.addParameter("contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName());
        context.addParameter("contextConfigLocation", AttachmentServicesConfig.class.getName());

        TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.disable();

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

    private static File createBaseDirectory() throws IOException {

        final File base = File.createTempFile("tmp-", "");

        if (!base.delete()) {
            throw new IOException(
                "Base directory couldn't be deleted: " + base.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (!base.mkdir()) {
            throw new IOException(
                "Base directory couldn't be created: " + base.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        return base;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which Tomcat version are you using? Jersey 3 requires Tomcat 10, while Spring requires Tomcat up to 9.0.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz v8.5.35

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Do I need Jersey at all? I do not get any error logs when starting tomcat without any Jersey dependendies in the POM.

Comment: If you are using CXF you don't need Jersey.

Comment: No, you don't need Jersey, CXF has an implementation of JAX-RS.

Answer (score 0):

You gave a too restrictive mapping for your `CXFServlet` (cf. [MappingMatch](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/MappingMatch.html) for the kind of mappings):

- you use the exact mapping `/I_Attachment_Services` that doesn't match anything beyond `/I_Attachment_Services`,
- you need a prefix mapping `/I_Attachment_Services/*` that matches `/I_Attachment_Services` and everything starting with `/I_Attachment_Services/`.

Just change the constant `SERVICE_PATH` to `/I_Attachment_Services/*`.

**Remark:** The line:

```java
factory.setAddress(factory.getAddress());
```

doesn't make sense. You probably wanted `factory.setAddress(null)` or something similar.

Comment: I changed the constant and the factory.setAddress line as you suggested but the response is still the same: HTTP 404

Comment: Just to make sure: do you prefix the requested URI path with the context path? You mention `GET /I_Attachment_Services/MaxMailSize HTTP/1.1` in your question, but this only works if you deploy the application with an empty path (or call the WAR file `ROOT.war`). In Eclipse you might have a different context path.